# checking values within array of arrays

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a Ruby script to sort through a bunch of CSV files. So I'm reading the file into a variable with CSV.read('file.csv') and I need to scan one of the columns to check if one of it's values either matches another, or matches the sum of two or more values.
My CSV looks something like:

```
title,day,total,flag
Cats,Friday,13,0
Cats,Friday,20,1
Cats,Friday,7,0
Cats,Friday,20,0
Cats,Tuesday,23
Cats,Tuesday,11,
Cats,Tuesday,5
Cats,Tuesday,6
Dogs,Monday,12
```

So I have this fairly convoluted solution that loops through the CSV array array and stores the index for each matching title in an array as well as the index for each matching day of the week that the title was seen, in another array. Now the part I'm stuck on is finding which value matches another/the sum of another. 
eg. 20 on Friday and 11 on Tuesday

What I have so far is:

```
fullfile = CSV.read('mycsv.csv', "r:ISO-8859-1")
i = 1
main = 1
ctitle = fullfile[1][0] ## Set current title to the first line in the CSV

mon = Array.new    ##
tue = Array.new    ## Arrays to store
wed = Array.new    ## the indexes for
thu = Array.new    ## days of the week
fri = Array.new    ## of a title
sat = Array.new    ##
sun = Array.new    ##

mi = 0   ## index variables
ti = 0   ## for each day array
wi = 0
thi = 0
fi = 0
sai = 0
sui = 0

while main < fullfile.count ## Main loop through entire file

  while fullfile[i][1] == ctitle  ## Loop to find matching titles

    case fullfile[i][2]  #check the current title 
    when "Tuesday"       #and store the index in
      tue[ti] = i      #the appropriate day array
      ti = ti + 1
    when "Friday"
      fri[fi] = i
      fi = fi + 1
    end
  i = i + 1
  end

## But now that I have the indexes
## how do I search fullfile[tue[ti][2]
## looking for matches

main = main + 1
if fullfile[main] == fullfile.last  # reset the main loop and
  cmovie = fullfile[main][1]      # move on to the next item
  main = 0
  i = 0
end
end
```

So now my plan is to loop through again using the indexes for Title and Day and find the matching number along with it's index so that I can make the appropriate changes to that line, but I have no clue how to do that.

EDIT:

The final result would be to edit the 'flag' column and put a 1 next to the matched number for that day and 0 for the rest.
e.g The 'total' Cats on Friday was 13, 20, 7, 20. Since 7+13=20 and/or there are 2x 20's, I would need to flag one of the 20's for Friday, the rest of Friday would be 0's like;

```
title,day,total,flag
Cats,Friday,13,0
Cats,Friday,20,1
Cats,Friday,7,0
Cats,Friday,20,0
```

Then do the same for Cats on Tuesday, which in this case was 23,11,5,6. So there're no matching numbers there, but the sum of 5 and 6 matches the 2nd row for Tuesday, making 11 the number I'm looking for. So I'd flag the row with total 11, and the rest of cats Tuesday would be 0

```
Cats,Tuesday,23,0
Cats,Tuesday,11,1
Cats,Tuesday,5,0
Cats,Tuesday,6,0
```

Once I'm done with Monday-Sunday for Cats, I'd do the same for Dogs and anything else in the Title column.

Comment: Would you show the desired output you expect to yield?

Comment: You can greatly simplify your code by passing `headers: true` to `CSV.read`. That lets you access columns by name e.g. `fullfile[0]['day']`. But I agree that without your expected output I can't help you further.

Comment: This problem still doesn't seem well-defined. Is there a guaranteed match for each animal/day? What if there are different pairs of rows that add up to different matching totals (e.g. 5, 2, 1, 6, 7)? Do both rows get flagged? What is the purpose of the flags? This seems like it could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that there will be multiple pairs as the real numbers are too large, but if that does occur, just the first row needs a positive flag. But generally, the sum of any pair will always match one of the numbers in a row. So the purpose of the flag is to find that number in order to make reporting easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you can do this

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.read('mycsv.csv', "r:ISO-8859-1", headers: true)

groups = csv.group_by { |row| [row['title'], row['day']] }

groups.each do |key, rows|
  # find two rows with matching totals, pick the first
  match, _ = rows.combination(2).find { |r1, r2| r1['total'].to_i == r2['total'].to_i }
  # else, find three rows where one total is the sum of the other two
  unless match
    _, _, match = rows.combination(3).find do |rs|
      rs.sort_by! { |r| r['total'].to_i }
      rs[0]['total'].to_i + rs[1]['total'].to_i == rs[2]['total'].to_i
    end
  end
  match["flag"] = 1 if match
end

# save
File.open('foo.csv', 'w') { |f| f.write(csv.to_s) }
```

Comment: Wow! That's a lot nicer than what I came up with, thanks. But how would I evaluate the values e.g [13, 20, 7, 20] to find that the matching pairs which in this case is 20, and relate it to it's row in csv[]?

Comment: @MattBlack I have edited my answer based on your further explanation of the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is going to take me a while to figure out what exactly this is doing, but when I run the code I get the following error: mycsv3.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method `r' for main:Object (NameError). I've thought maybe it was a quirk with ruby OSX, but I get the same on linux and Windows with ruby version 2+

Comment: Figured out that the r arrays on line 14 were meant to be rs, so it works perfectly now. Thanks sooo much Max!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not realize what are you trying to achieve, but I can help you to start.

```
csv = CSV.read('/tmp/csv.csv').map do |e| 
  e.take(3)
end.inject({}) { |memo, e| 
  ((memo[e[1]] ||= {})[e[0]] ||= []) << e[2]
  memo
end
```

will give you:

```
=> {
   "Friday" => {
    "Cats" => [
      [0] "13",
      [1] "20",
      [2] "7",
      [3] "20"
    ]
  },
   "Monday" => {
    "Dogs" => [
      [0] "12"
    ]
  },
  "Tuesday" => {
    "Cats" => [
      [0] "23",
      [1] "11",
      [2] "5",
      [3] "6"
    ]
  },
      "day" => {
    "title" => [
      [0] "total"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure it’s way easier to go further from here. Hope it helps.

Whether you have the desired output provided, I could try to lead this further.